# JSON Parse Error when DIV used as INPUT

Tags: javascript, json

Take a look at below fiddle:

[JSON Parse Error](https://jsfiddle.net/kaushalpapers/on07vpyk/)

```
>    var divText = document.getElementById('div').innerText; var divJson
> = JSON.parse(divText);
```

When I click parse JSON button, it works fine.

Now when I copy, json text from textArea and paste it to DIV and click parse JSON button it throws below error.

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 0

I checked if it has any extra characters but I failed to find any.

I made DIV as content editable. My goal is to treat DIV as INPUT and take JSON from it and parse it.

I do not want to use textArea as input. That is my restriction.

Please advise

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: my guess without looking is it does not like linebreaks or some other special character that gets copied form the textarea

Answer (score 0):

Copy pasting the JSON from textArea actually has space character issue. You either need to format your JSON well or use a well spaced JSON.

You can do this below to fix your stuff.

```
var textAreaJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(textAreaText), "", " "));
```